# how to make active charcoal soap rinse away?

Tags: diy, personal-hygiene

I've created active charcoal soap by mixing active charcoal, aloe vera, and witch hazel.  Problematically, the color clings to my skin and is very difficult to rinse off.  What natural agents might I add to the cleanser in order to cause it to bind to itself more and rinse more easily off the body?

Comment: Hi Walrus! Did you find a solution to this interesting issue?

Comment: sorry nope.  I think you basically have to use lye in order to get this behavior, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I know of:

1: High PH (alkaline) cleaner such as borax, soda ash, baking soda. If you are able to raise the PH above the PH of the charcoal, it will come right off.

2: Natural solvents such as orange oil or lemon/lime juice. Natural solvents that contain citric acid will remove it as well.

3: Distilled white vinegar. Opposite on PH scale so it will neutralize and allow you to rinse off.

Comment: haven't tested / verified, but this sounds well-reasoned